# MongoDB Aggregation Pipeline fetch data group by month in a date range

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am using an aggregate in MongoDB with PHP to fetch data for a date range. The result I am trying to achieve should like this for the date range: ISODate("2016-05-24T15:08:32Z") to ISODate("2016-05-24T15:08:32Z")

```
["year" => 2016
"month" => 6
"scoring" =>238
"count" => 96],

["year" => 2016
"month" => 65
"scoring" =>238
"count" => 96]
```

The code looks like:

```
$pipeline =
  [
    ['$match'=>[
          'testId' => $id,
          'date' => [
                            '$gte'=> $start(),
                            '$lte' =>$end()
                          ],
                ]
    ],

    ['$group' => [
                '_id' => [false],
                'scoring' => ['$sum' => '$scoring'],
                'count'  => ['$sum' => 1],
              ],
          ]
  ];
```

I used already $project to break the month and year down but I am struggling to do that for a date range and not for a specific date.
Any ideas if this is possible?

Comment: You can include [month](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/month/) and [year](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/year/) as grouping key instead of [false]. Something like `['$group' => [
                '_id' => 
                            [
                                'year' =>  ['$year' => '$date'],
                                'month' => ['$month' =>'$date'],
                            ]..`